# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Reposit' : Invocation of init method failed

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, beancreationexception

I am getting the below error when trying to bring the application up.
I tried mltiple solution but none seems to be working.

*Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.test.base.repository.TestRespositoryCustom.findResultByCodeAndProfile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property findResultByCodeAndProfile found for type Test!

................
................

............ 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findResultByCodeAndProfile found for type Test!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]*

My service class is calling findResultByCodeAndProfile method which call interface TestRespositoryCustom and the implementation of which is 
there below in TestRespositoryImpl class.

"Test.java is the entity class"

-- Service class.

```
@Autowired
TestRepository testRepository;

     public void getHotelProfileLatestTest(String hotelCode)
    {
        List<TestDto> testList = testRepository.findResultByCodeAndProfile(secondaryCode, "profile");
        //
        //
    }
```

-- TestRepository interface

```
public interface TestRepository extends BaseRepository<Test, Long>, TestRepositoryCustom {

    {
    @Query(TestQueries.NOTE_QRY)
    Page<TestDto> getHistory(@Param("Key") String Key,
            @Param("Value") String Value);
    }
```

--  BaseRepository interface.

```
        @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface BaseRepository <T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryByExampleExecutor<T>{

}
```

-- TestRespositoryCustom

```
public interface TestRespositoryCustom
{
    public List<TestDto> findResultByCodeAndProfile(String testObjKey, String testObjValue);
}
```

-- TestRespositoryImpl

```
public class TestRespositoryImpl extends BaseRepositoryCustom implements TestRespositoryCustom
{
   @Override
    public List<TestDto> findResultByCodeAndProfile(String testObjKey, String testObjValue)
    {
        String sql = TC_NOTE_QRY;
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
        query.setMaxResults(3);
        query.setParameter("testObjKey", testObjKey);
        query.setParameter("testObjValue", testObjValue);
        return (List) query.getResultList();
    }
```

-- BaseRepositoryCustom

```
public class BaseRepositoryCustom {

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema}")
    public String defaultSchema;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

}
```

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't compile. Your implementation overrides a findAll() method that doesn't exist, and doesn't override the findResultByCodeAndProfile method declared in the interface.

Comment: That was copy paste error from eclipse to here.. My bad, i corrected it.

Comment: The class name should be TestRespositoryCustomImpl (i.e. the name of the interface folloxed by Impl) See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior